# Lightning record page updates appear to be saved, but they are not

Tags: lightning-record-page

We have a single and elaborate Lightning record page for Leads. With a lot of conditional component visibilities. In total, the Lightning record page consists of 8 tab components, of which at any time exactly one is shown. The tab components hold a total of 30 tabs (so on average less than 4 per tab component).

When we add a tab, saving seems to succeed. It takes a while, but we get the confirmation "Changed saved". Activation not needed: that has already been done.

Reloading the Lead page: no changes apparent (we have already disabled session caching on server side). Edit page once more and all changes have been undone. But the date of modification of the Lightning record page has been updated.

As an experiment, we deleted one of the existing tabs, saved the Lightning record page. Result: the tab was no longer visible.

We then added the removed tab back to its original position. Result: the tab was still *not* visible. Editing the Lightning record page showed that the change had been undone.

I have never seen this in Salesforce, that updates just disappear. What could be the cause? This Lightning record page was created a number of Sales Cloud releases ago, has some kind of limit on tabs or tab components been introduced lately?

Update: another sysadmin is able to add tabs to the tab components. We both have the same, standard, sysadmin profile. So there is no problem with limits, but somehow it matters who edits the Lightning record page?

I cloned the Lightning record page, making me the owner of that clone (well, I hope, because I don't know how to check that, I don't know how to query for the owner of a FlexiPage). I activated it as the standard page for the organisation for the desktop. Again I tried to add a tab and again, upon reopening it via Edit page, my change was gone.

So I went to a completely unrelated and much simpler page, the Contact page. Same there: I can remove tabs, but I cannot add any. That is, the UI gives me the impression that I can, but Save somehow ignores additions. Do I need a special permission to add tabs to a page?

Comment: Browser console is the best friend here can you tell us what is happening there. Can you clone the page and assign to a profile to check for changes similar happens once I changed the name and it works.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I appreciate the response, but browser console is apparently not my best friend. There are so many messages in the console, I have no idea which ones are relevant. And when should I watch the console: during first Save, during opening of page, during opening of Edit Page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, not for the first time, the problem was located between the keyboard and the chair.

I assumed that adding a tab with a name as Chatter or Activity would also add the Chatter/Activity content. But adding a tab just adds the tab, without any content. 'Save' apparently removes tabs without content. No warning or error, the tabs are silently removed.

Which explains all of the issues above. Deletions always work. The other sysadmin assumed that I knew that I needed to add content to a tab (thanks for working remotely) and he had no problems.

So: when adding a tab, also add content. Empty tabs are removed without warning.